# Gradle 7, Are Android Build-Configuration documentations outdated?

Tags: android, gradle, documentation, android-gradle-7.0

Going through the documentation of [Gradle's build configuration](https://developer.android.com/studio/build) I can see several conflicts with my build on `Android Studio 2020.3.1` using `Gradle 7.0.3`.

For example, in the documentation is says that `allProjects` block for repositories settings used by all modules should be added to the root `build.gradle` while in fact it only allows me to configure modules repositories in the `settings.gradle` under `dependencyResolutionManagement` block.

Another example is applying plugins to application modules, in documentations it says the first line should be:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

While the one used in my build is:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}
```

What I also noticed is that also JitPack uses the same configurations suggested in that documentations page for using a JitPack published library in projects:

> Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

> Step 2. Add the dependency

```
dependencies {
        implementation 'com.github.arcm111.ScaleNumberPicker:final:1.0.1'
}
```

So my question is, are these documentation pages outdated, is `Gradle 7` not fully supported yet, or am I looking at the wrong documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in the documentation is says that allProjects block for repositories settings used by all modules should be added to the root build.gradle while in fact it only allows me to configure modules repositories in the settings.gradle under dependencyResolutionManagement block.

You may wish to ask a separate Stack Overflow question with a minimum verifiable example and details of your errors. [This GitLab repo, in tag `v2.2`](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v2.2) contains a multi-module Android Studio project using Gradle 7.0.2 that uses `allProjects` for configuring repositories.

> Another example is applying plugins to application modules, in documentations it says the first line should be... While the one used in my build is

Either syntax works. The `plugins` approach has been available for a year or so in Android Studio projects. The project that I linked to above uses the older `apply plugin` syntax. [This sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-andexplore/-/tree/v2.2/T34-Work/ToDo), by contrast, uses `plugins`.

> are these documentation pages outdated, is Gradle 7 not fully supported yet, or am I looking at the wrong documentation?

None of the above, AFAICT. `allProjects` and `apply plugin` still work, at least with Gradle 7.0.2.

Comment: When I add `allProjects` to top-level `build.gradle` is gives me the following error `Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by build file 'build.gradle'`

Comment: @razz: IIRC, there is something in your `settings.gradle` that is telling Gradle to not want `allprojects`.

Comment: This is my `settings.gradle` file content: `dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "SNPTest"
include ':app'
`. It's the one generated by Android Studio, I didn't change any settings.

Comment: @razz: Remove the `dependencyResolutionManagement` closure. That specifically says "do not support project-based repositories", which is what `allProjects` is part of.

Comment: What I'm wondering about is, if these are the default configuration now in Gradle, then shouldn't android documentations be updated to be relevant to the latest version of Gradle?

Comment: @razz: Ideally, the documentation would mention both approaches. However, right now, ~99.9% of Android Studio projects were not created using the Arctic Fox new-project wizard, and therefore are unlikely to be using `dependencyResolutionManagement`.